# Add Filters based on some condition java 8

Tags: stream, java-8

I need to filter a list of employees based of some parameter like firstName , lastName etc etc. These parameters are user defined user can choose all filter or a combination of filters.

```
public List<Employee> getFilterList(String firstName,String lastName)
{
    List<Employee> empList = empRepository.getEmployees();

    Stream<Employee> empStream=empList.stream();

   if(firstName!=null)
   {
     empStream= empStream.filter(e-> e.getFirstname().equals(firstName))
   }

   if(lastName!=null)
   {
     empStream= empStream.filter(e-> e.getlastName().equals(lastName))
   }

   return empStream.collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Is this a correct way of doing this?

**Note:** the above code is working fine i am just looking for another better approach (if any).

**Case 1:**  `getFilterList(null,null)` return list of all employees

**Case 2:** `getFilterList("abc",null)` return list of all employees with first name abc.

Comment: Looks ok to me, are you having issues with it? Do you care about case comparison (I.e. Upper and lower case)?

Comment: No , I do not have any issue with this code and its working fine too. But i was not sure about this approach.

Answer (score 5):

It shows list `empList` according to the parameter of `firstName` filter or filtering according to the parameter `lastName`, the code pattern are almost same. So I came up with the following code.

```
public List<Employee> getFilterList(String firstName,String lastName){

    List<Employee> empList = empRepository.getEmployees();

    return empList.stream().filter(getPredicateBiFun.apply(firstName,Employee::getFirstName))
                           .filter(getPredicateBiFun.apply(lastName,Employee::getLastName))
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

It seems more like Java8 style. And here is a static property `getPredicateBiFun` you see which can get the corresponding `Predicate<Employee>` expressions according to the parameters. So it's just a `BiFunction` and a good pattern for what we want.

```
private static BiFunction<String, Function<Employee, String>, Predicate<Employee>> getPredicateBiFun = (name, getNameFun) -> employee -> name == null ? true : name.equals(getNameFun.apply(employee));
```

That's all :)

Comment: Will this attempt to execute the filter only if `firstName` or `lastName` is provided ? Say, total 10 records. `firstName` is present and filters 5 records. `lastName` filter is NOT present - now, will it be attempted to filter the remaining 5 records with `lastName` ? (i.e will each of the remaning 5 records be iterated or visited ?)

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it this way:

```
List<Predicate<Employee>> predicateList = new ArrayList<>();

predicateList.add(emp -> firstName == null || (emp.firstName != null && emp.firstName.equals(firstName)));
predicateList.add(emp -> lastName == null || (emp.lastName != null && emp.lastName.equals(lastName)));

empStream.filter(emp -> {
  Stream<Predicate<Employee>> predicateStream = predicateList.stream();
  return predicateStream.map(predicate -> predicate.test(emp)).reduce((a, b) -> a && b).get();
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Based on user's choice, you need to create `predicateList` by adding predicates.

`predicateStream.map(predicate -> predicate.test(emp))` returns a `Stream<Boolean>`. This stream contains values which is result of applying a predicate (ie `predicate.test(emp)`) on `emp` instance. Then `reduce((a, b) -> a && b)` checks if all results in stream were `true` or not. In the end `true` or `false` is returned, on the basis of which `filter` decides whether an `emp` object should be selected or not.

*Note* that `Stream<Predicate<Employee>> predicateStream` is created for each `Employee` object in `empStream`, which might involve some overhead.

Comment: @SandeepBhardwaj Added explanation.

Comment: The code is not workig for **Case 1:** `getFilterList(null,null)`, in that case it should return all records, **Case 2:** `getFilterList("abc",null)` in this case all emp with first name abc as first name.

Comment: As I mentioned, you need to create predicates dynamically based on user's input, here I have just shown you how you can apply one or more conditions on a list of objects. Don't just use predicates that I added in `predicateList`. It was just example.

Comment: @SandeepBhardwaj updated `predicateList` based on your specific requirement. It should work for both of the cases now.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the second condition takes presidance over the first and if both `firstName` and `lastName` are `null`, you return the list of the `Employee`. A lot of the conditionals that you have put are therefore evaluated even though their evaluation is not required. I would have done this in along following lines:

```
return firstName == null && lastName == null ? 
                empList : 
                (lastName != null ? 
                        empList.stream().filter(emp -> emp.lastname.equals(lastName) :
                        empList.stream().filter(emp -> emp.firstName.equals(firstName))
                ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the most optimal way, but it gets rid of the ifs:

```
List<Employee> empList = empRepository.getEmployees();

return empList.stream()
            .filter(e -> firstName == null || e.getFirstname().equals(firstName))
            .filter(e -> lastName == null || e.getlastName().equals(lastName))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Struggled on the excat same thing. For anyone searching for another way:

```
empList.stream()
    .filter(firstName != null ? e -> e.getFirstName().equals(firstName) : e -> true)
    .filter(lastName != null ? e -> e.getLastName().equals(lastName) : e -> true)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Using a *[ternary operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation#Computer_science)* to apply the filter or not (if not, just set to true in my case)